# Total for columns in dynamic table using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, row

My issue is when I enter the values of Quantity and Price to calculate the total, it will be calculated, but when I add another line, the total value is calculated from the last entered values of Quantity and Price as shown in the figure below :

[image]

My code is below :

```
        class AjouterFacture extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              rowData: [],
              Produits: [],
              Quantite: "",
              Prix: ""
            };

            this.handleRowChange = this.handleRowChange.bind(this);
            this.handleRowDelete = this.handleRowDelete.bind(this);
            this.handleRowAdd = this.handleRowAdd.bind(this);
            this.getTotal = this.getTotal.bind(this);
            this.pushToCaller = this.pushToCaller.bind(this);
          }
  handleQuantiteChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          Quantite: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }
      handleselectprdtChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          selectprdt: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }
      handlePrixChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          Prix: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }

          pushToCaller() {
            this.handleRowChange( {
              Quantite: parseInt(this.state.Quantite, 10),
              selectprdt: this.state.selectprdt,
              Prix: parseFloat(this.state.Prix),
            });
          }


          render() {

            return (<div className="animated fadeIn">


         <h6> Veuillez ajouter au moins un produit : </h6>
                <Table  >
                <thead >
                          <tr>
                            <th>PRODUIT</th>
                            <th>QUANTITE</th>
                            <th>PRIX UNITAIRE</th>
                            <th>TOTAL</th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                        {this.state.rowData.map((index) =>

                        <tr key={index} id={index} 
                        onChange={this.handleRowChange}>


                 <td> <Input type="select" name="selectedcl" id="selectcl"
                                  placeholder="Veuillez sélectionner un produit"  value={this.state.rowData.selectprdt}
                  onChange={this.handleselectprdtChange} >
                   <option  key={-1} hidden>Choisisr un produit</option>


                             {  this.state.Produits.map((pdt, i) => 
                             <option key={i} >{pdt.Nomp}</option>
                             )} 


                              </Input>
                            </td>
                            <td><Input type="number" 
                                  placeholder="0" value={this.state.rowData.Quantite} onChange={this.handleQuantiteChange}/></td>
                            <td>
                                 <InputGroup ><Input type="text" 
                                  value={this.state.rowData.Prix} onChange={this.handlePrixChange} />
                                  <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                      <InputGroupText><i ></i></InputGroupText>
                                    </InputGroupAddon>
                                         </InputGroup >
                                  </td>

                            <td >
                             <p >{this.state.Quantite * this.state.Prix}  </p>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <Button onClick={this.handleRowDelete} active style={center} >Effacer</Button>
              </td> </tr> )} 



                          <tr>

                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><Button onClick={this.handleRowAdd} >Ajouter une ligne</Button></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                  <tr>

                    <th></th>
                    <th >Grand total :</th>
                    <th>{this.getTotal()} </th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
        </tfoot>

                </Table>


                </div>);
          }
          getTotal() {
            let grandTotal = 0;
            const rowTotals = this.state.rowData.map(row => this.state.Quantite *  this.state.Prix);
            if (rowTotals.length > 0) {
              grandTotal = rowTotals.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
            }
            return grandTotal;
          }
         handleRowChange(row, data) {
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy[row] = data;
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy

            });
          }  
          handleRowDelete(row) {
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy.splice(row, 1);
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy
            });
          }
         handleRowAdd() {
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy.push({selectprdt:'', Quantite : "", Prix :"" });
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy
            });
          }

        }
        export default AjouterFacture;
```

I want the total column will be calculated for each row.

How can I correct that please?

Comment: where is handleQuantiteChange and handlePrixChange declared in the component? I don't see these declared anywhere in your component

Comment: @HemadriDasari I edit the post by adding them

Comment: Ok. Looks like the issue is with the id ie.e, this.state.id. You are passing this.state.id to this.handleRowChange as a first parameter but I don't see the id preinitialised and modified anywhere in your component

Comment: @HemadriDasari I delete this.state.id because I haven't id and it's still the same issue.

Comment: Try to understand the concept the id is required in order to set the values for each row. don't delete it

Comment: I have the id of the row : `{this.state.rowData.map((index) =>
                
                <tr key={index} id={index} 
                onChange={this.handleRowChange}>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178128/discussion-between-codelover-and-hemadri-dasari).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You several issues with the code you provided, I will try to list most of them below:

- The method you are using for updating the rows is not advisable and will probably introduce lots of error, instead of having a temporary price/quantity and update the data later, you should directly update them in the state.
- You did not bind few methods:

  `this.handleQuantiteChange = this.handleQuantiteChange.bind(this);
  this.handlePrixChange = this.handlePrixChange.bind(this);
  this.handleselectprdtChange = this.handleselectprdtChange.bind(this);`
- In the total column you should print the price of this specific row, not of the temporary variables. You should also list the price/quantity of the specific row.
- The `map` function invokes with `(data, index)` not only `(index)`
- You need to bind the `index` with the invocation of the `onChange` handler to get the targeted row. Same goes for the `handleRowDelete`.

Here is your corrected code:

```
class AjouterFacture extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rowData: [],
      Produits: [],
      id: 0
    };

    this.handleQuantiteChange = this.handleQuantiteChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePrixChange = this.handlePrixChange.bind(this);
    this.handleselectprdtChange = this.handleselectprdtChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRowDelete = this.handleRowDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleRowAdd = this.handleRowAdd.bind(this);
    this.getTotal = this.getTotal.bind(this);
  }
  handleQuantiteChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {Quantite: parseInt(value, 10)});
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleselectprdtChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {selectprdt: value});
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handlePrixChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {Prix: parseInt(value, 10)});
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <h6> Veuillez ajouter au moins un produit : </h6>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>PRODUIT</th>
              <th>QUANTITE</th>
              <th>PRIX UNITAIRE</th>
              <th>TOTAL</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.rowData.map((data, index) => (
              <tr key={index} id={index}>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <Input
                    type="select"
                    name="selectedcl"
                    id="selectcl"
                    placeholder="Veuillez sélectionner un produit"
                    value={data.selectprdt}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleselectprdtChange(index, e.targe.value)}
                  >
                    <option key={-1} hidden>
                      Choisisr un produit
                    </option>

                    {this.state.Produits.map((pdt, i) => (
                      <option key={i}>{pdt.Nomp}</option>
                    ))}
                  </Input>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Input
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="0"
                    value={data.Quantite || 0}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleQuantiteChange(index, e.target.value)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <InputGroup>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      value={data.Prix || 0}
                      onChange={(e) => this.handlePrixChange(index, e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                      <InputGroupText>
                        <i />
                      </InputGroupText>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
                  </InputGroup>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>{(data.Quantite || 0) * (data.Prix || 0)} </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Button
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleRowDelete(index)}
                    active
                    style={"center"}
                  >
                    Effacer
                  </Button>
                </td>{" "}
              </tr>
            ))}

            <tr>
              <td />
              <td />
              <td />
              <td />
              <td>
                <Button onClick={this.handleRowAdd} style={center}>Ajouter une ligne</Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th />
              <th>Grand total :</th>
              <th>{this.getTotal()} </th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getTotal() {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    const rowTotals = this.state.rowData.map(
      row => (row.Quantite * row.Prix) || 0
    );
    if (rowTotals.length > 0) {
      grandTotal = rowTotals.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
    }
    return grandTotal;
  }

  handleRowDelete(row) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.splice(row, 1);
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleRowAdd() {
    let id = this.state.id;
        id = id++;
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.push({
      selectprdt: "",
      Quantite: 0,
      Prix: 0
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy,
      id: id
    });
  }
}

export default AjouterFacture;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed  for your explanation! It works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try below updated code.

```
class AjouterFacture extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              rowData: [],
              Produits: [],
              Quantite: "",
              Prix: "",
              id:0
            };

            this.handleRowChange = this.handleRowChange.bind(this);
            this.handleRowDelete = this.handleRowDelete.bind(this);
            this.handleRowAdd = this.handleRowAdd.bind(this);
            this.getTotal = this.getTotal.bind(this);
            this.pushToCaller = this.pushToCaller.bind(this);
          }
  handleQuantiteChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          Quantite: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }
      handleselectprdtChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          selectprdt: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }
      handlePrixChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          Prix: e.target.value
        }, this.pushToCaller);
      }

          pushToCaller() {
            this.handleRowChange(this.state.id, {
              Quantite: parseInt(this.state.Quantite, 10),
              selectprdt: this.state.selectprdt,
              Prix: parseFloat(this.state.Prix),
            });
          }


          render() {

            return (<div className="animated fadeIn">


         <h6> Veuillez ajouter au moins un produit : </h6>
                <Table  >
                <thead >
                          <tr>
                            <th>PRODUIT</th>
                            <th>QUANTITE</th>
                            <th>PRIX UNITAIRE</th>
                            <th>TOTAL</th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                        {this.state.rowData.map((index) =>

                        <tr key={index} id={index} 
                        onChange={this.handleRowChange}>


                 <td> <Input type="select" name="selectedcl" id="selectcl"
                                  placeholder="Veuillez sélectionner un produit"  value={this.state.rowData.selectprdt}
                  onChange={this.handleselectprdtChange} >
                   <option  key={-1} hidden>Choisisr un produit</option>


                             {  this.state.Produits.map((pdt, i) => 
                             <option key={i} >{pdt.Nomp}</option>
                             )} 


                              </Input>
                            </td>
                            <td><Input type="number" 
                                  placeholder="0" value={this.state.rowData.Quantite} onChange={this.handleQuantiteChange}/></td>
                            <td>
                                 <InputGroup ><Input type="text" 
                                  value={this.state.rowData.Prix} onChange={this.handlePrixChange} />
                                  <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                      <InputGroupText><i ></i></InputGroupText>
                                    </InputGroupAddon>
                                         </InputGroup >
                                  </td>

                            <td >
                             <p >{this.state.Quantite * this.state.Prix}  </p>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <Button onClick={this.handleRowDelete} active style={center} >Effacer</Button>
              </td> </tr> )} 



                          <tr>

                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><Button onClick={this.handleRowAdd} >Ajouter une ligne</Button></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                  <tr>

                    <th></th>
                    <th >Grand total :</th>
                    <th>{this.getTotal()} </th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
        </tfoot>

                </Table>


                </div>);
          }
          getTotal() {
            let grandTotal = 0;
            const rowTotals = this.state.rowData.map(row => this.state.Quantite *  this.state.Prix);
            if (rowTotals.length > 0) {
              grandTotal = rowTotals.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
            }
            return grandTotal;
          }
         handleRowChange(row, data) {
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy[row] = data;
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy

            });
          }  
          handleRowDelete(row) {
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy.splice(row, 1);
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy
            });
          }
         handleRowAdd() {
            let id = this.state.id;
                id = id++;
            const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
            rowDataCopy.push({selectprdt:'', Quantite : "", Prix :"" });
            this.setState({
              rowData: rowDataCopy,
              id: id
            });
          }

        }
        export default AjouterFacture;
```